# WifiManager.AddNetowrk on Android 9 return -1 on Galaxy S8

Tags: android, xamarin, galaxy, wifimanager, samsung-galaxy

I am making Xamarin App connecting specific wifi.
Above android 10, I've use AddNetworkSuggestion and works fine.
This method does not work with Android 9, so when it is called on Android 9, I am calling older apis.

On Android 9, I am using AddNetwork. and some device works fine but AddNetwork return -1 on multiple Samsung Galaxy S8 Devices.

```
                var config = new WifiConfiguration();
                config.Ssid = '"' + ssid + '"';
                config.PreSharedKey = '"' + password + '"';
                config.AllowedAuthAlgorithms.Set((int)AuthAlgorithmType.Open);
                config.AllowedProtocols.Set((int)ProtocolType.Wpa); // For WPA
                config.AllowedProtocols.Set((int)ProtocolType.Rsn); // For WPA2
                config.AllowedKeyManagement.Set((int)KeyManagementType.WpaPsk);
                config.AllowedKeyManagement.Set((int)KeyManagementType.WpaEap);
                config.AllowedKeyManagement.Set((int)KeyManagementType.Sae);
                config.AllowedPairwiseCiphers.Set((int)PairwiseCipherType.Tkip);
                config.AllowedPairwiseCiphers.Set((int)PairwiseCipherType.Ccmp);
                config.AllowedPairwiseCiphers.Set((int)PairwiseCipherType.Gcmp256);
                config.AllowedGroupCiphers.Set((int)GroupCipherType.Tkip);
                config.AllowedGroupCiphers.Set((int)GroupCipherType.Ccmp);
                config.AllowedGroupCiphers.Set((int)GroupCipherType.Gcmp256);
                config.AllowedGroupCiphers.Set((int)GroupCipherType.Wep40);
                config.AllowedGroupCiphers.Set((int)GroupCipherType.Wep104);
                var addreturn = WifiManager.AddNetwork(config);
```

I am guessing Galaxy has some specific extention or customize that does not allow AddNetwork but can not figure out what is it.

Anyone have an idea to fix it?

Comment: Do you have all required permissions? I think it's edit network, internet, and location or coarse location

Comment: @JuanSturla Thank you. Yes I set permission below.
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
INTERNET
ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: Those permissions are inside the android.manifest, but also ask during runtime?

Comment: No it did not ask runtime. I will research how and try to ask and get back

Comment: You can use [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android)

Comment: I've check and request onCreate, all permission, and it asked in first time. Still it did not fix problem. AddNetwork returns -1. @JuanSturla Thanks for the Idea though.

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#addNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration))  It was deprecated for api 29, also `Compatibility Note: For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will always fail and return -1.`

Comment: I've changed target version to Android 9.0 API Level 28. Still returning -1. @JuanSturla Thanks anyway.

Comment: How about use addNetworkSuggestions  instead?

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT Thanks for the comment. I tried to call addNetworkSuggestions but on Android 9 it throws exception.

Comment: what kind of exception?